# Fetch first X rows from parent table regardless of rows produced by joining one to many child table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two database tables PERSON_TABLE, and FILE_TABLE with an one to many relationship. I need to be able to limit the result to give me the first X number of rows of persons. While being able to *join* and filter on columns in the FILE_TABLE. I need to get the first two persons, regardless of how many rows the join on the file table produces.

**PERSON_TABLE**

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Eric |
| 2 | John |

**FILE_TABLE**

| ID | PERSON_ID | FILE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.xml |
| 2 | 1 | 2.xml |
| 3 | 2 | 3.xml |

**Attempt - Joining and fetch next**

```sql
select *
from (select *
      from person_table person,
           file_table file
      where person.id = file.person_id)
offset 0 rows fetch next 2 rows only;
```

Result: This won't work, since Eric has two files, so this will only return rows containing Eric.

**Workaround Attempt - listagg**

By using listagg I can *concatinate* the FILE_TABLE rows I need into the PERSON_TABLE rows, but I do not think it looks very elegant.

Is there another obvious way of doing this that I am missing?

Comment: Use a CTE to get the PERSON_TABLE rows that you want and then join that to the FILE_TABLE

Comment: Would you expect to return a person if they had no rows in the file_table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to filter the people then join. If you want rows where each person has at least one file:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   person_table p
         WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM file_table f WHERE p.id = f.person_id)
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY ) p
       INNER JOIN file_table f
       ON  p.id = f.person_id;
```

or, using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       file_name,
       person_id
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         f.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.name, p.id) AS rnk
  FROM   person_table p
         INNER JOIN file_table f
         ON  p.id = f.person_id
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person_table (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE file_table (file_name, person_id) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output the first two people with files:

| ID | NAME | FILE_NAME | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | A | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | B | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | C | 1 |
| 3 | Carol | D | 3 |

If you also want to filter the number of files per person then use a `LATERAL` join and filter inside the lateral join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   person_table p
         WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM file_table f WHERE p.id = f.person_id)
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY ) p
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   file_table f
         WHERE  p.id = f.person_id
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
       );
```

or, again, with analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       file_name,
       person_id
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         f.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.name, p.id) AS rnk,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY f.file_name) AS rn
  FROM   person_table p
         INNER JOIN file_table f
         ON  p.id = f.person_id
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2
AND    rn <= 2;
```

Which both output:

| ID | NAME | FILE_NAME | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | A | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | B | 1 |
| 3 | Carol | D | 3 |

If you want to get the first 2 people, regardless of if they have zero-or-more files, then use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   person_table
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN file_table f
       ON p.id = f.person_id;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       file_name,
       person_id
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         f.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.name, p.id) AS rnk
  FROM   person_table p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN file_table f
         ON  p.id = f.person_id
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2
```

Which outputs:

| ID | NAME | FILE_NAME | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | A | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | B | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | C | 1 |
| 2 | Betty | *null* | *null* |

And, if you want to filter the files-per-person then, again, use a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   person_table
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT *
         FROM   file_table f
         WHERE  p.id = f.person_id
         FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
       )
       ON (1 = 1);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       file_name,
       person_id
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         f.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY p.name, p.id) AS rnk,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY f.file_name) AS rn
  FROM   person_table p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN file_table f
         ON  p.id = f.person_id
)
WHERE  rnk <= 2
AND    rn <= 2
```

| ID | NAME | FILE_NAME | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | A | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | B | 1 |
| 2 | Betty | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fvVtXhVE)