# Fetch N elements from table while joining other table with one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data:

collection:

| id | label | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Collection of CVs #1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | Collection of business cards #1 | 2023-02-01 |
| 3 | Collection of CVs #2 | 2023-03-01 |

model:

| id | label | type | format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |
| 2 | Business cards | business card | 8.5x5.5 |

document:

| id | label | collection_id | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe CV | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | John Dorian CV | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | John Travolta CV | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | John Malkovich business card | 2 | 2 |

A collection contains multiple documents, and a document has one model.

**How do I fetch only collections containing CVs (along with the CVs in question) while limiting the number of collections returned?**

(*Collections' labels are only here for clarity, the only way to know if a document is a CV is through its model*)

With the following query:

```sql
select *
from collection
join document on document.collection_id = collection.id
join model on document.model_id = model.id
where model.type = 'cv'
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

I get the following result, which obviously gives me the first two rows:

| id | label | created_at | id | label | collection_id | model_id | id | label | type | format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Collection of CVs #1 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | John Doe CV | 1 | 1 | 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |
| 1 | Collection of CVs #1 | 2023-01-01 | 2 | John Dorian CV | 1 | 1 | 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |

What I want instead is **the first two collections containing CVs**, along with the CVs in question:

| id | label | created_at | id | label | collection_id | model_id | id | label | type | format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Collection of CVs #1 | 2023-01-01 | 1 | John Doe CV | 1 | 1 | 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |
| 1 | Collection of CVs #1 | 2023-01-01 | 2 | John Dorian CV | 1 | 1 | 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |
| 3 | Collection of CVs #2 | 2023-03-01 | 3 | John Travolta CV | 3 | 1 | 1 | CVs | cv | 21x29.7 |

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/30750

Comment: just remove "fetch first 2 rows only;"  from your query !, if is this is not you want kindly tell  a little more

Comment: I edited my first message and the expected output, I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use window function `dense_rank()` to limit number of collection that should be selected

```
select *
from (
  select *, dense_rank() over (order by c.id) as rnk
  from collection c
  join document d on d.collection_id = c.id
  join model m on m.id = d.model_id and m.type = 'cv'
) as s
where rnk <= 2
```

Here, you get results with less than two distinct collection_id. But possibly more than one per collection_id.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GtyCYHzh)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried that but it doesn't give the expected result. In your query, the `fetch first 2 rows` clause will return 2 collections regardless of whether or not they contains CV.

Comment: I edited my first message and the expected output, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: For the record, I also found this question on SO after posting mine and getting answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044872/fetch-first-x-rows-from-parent-table-regardless-of-rows-produced-by-joining-one?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

the response from @SelVazi will actually list you the first two collection, mine will display every collection, considere check his.

edit based on your comment:

```
select c.*, d.*, m.*
from document d
inner join collection c on c.id = d.collection_id
inner join model m on m.id = d.model_id and m.type = 'cv'
```

it will return every collections and documents with model type 'cv'

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried that but it doesn't give the expected result.

In your query, the `fetch first 2 rows` clause will return 2 collections regardless of whether or not they contains CV.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope below query can help**

```
select *
from collection
join document on document.collection_id = collection.id and collection.id in(1,3) 
join model on document.model_id = model.id
where model.type = 'cv';
```